# Display Selected Month Values in mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In MYSQL database, I have the date column which contains date in format [29-11-2012].
I would like to display the values based upon month selected by user via php page.

For Example, If user selects OCT then this should display all the other columns for this particular month.

Can you suggest SQL Query for this?

Thanks,
Shail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(formdate,'%d-%m-%Y'))
```

like this condition

Basically mysql stores dates in yyyy-mm-dd format only..

Comment: Hi, I have tried this option as SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE MONTH(formdate) = 10 however, this displaying o rows

Comment: Can you post the same dates in ur table

Comment: Dates in my table were like....29-09-2012
12-09-2012
29-09-2012
21-09-2012
21-09-2012
21-09-2012
27-09-2012
27-09-2012
27-09-2012
27-09-2012
27-09-2012
27-09-2012
27-09-2012

Comment: use this MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(formdate,'%d-%m-%Y')) = 10